# running Haxeflixel hello world project throws error

Tags: compiler-errors, haxeflixel

I did the setup for haxeflixel in the documentation, installing haxe and lime and stuff. I made the hello world project, and ran it with

```
lime test html5
```

and it came up with this...
[image: I did the setup correctly, im not sure whats happening]

I did the
setup correctly, I'm not sure why the source code for Haxeflixel is throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

What version of lime you have?

```
haxelib list
```

Install and use 7.8.0 for OpenFL 9.0.2

Comment: I ran the haxelib list command, I have lime 7.8.0 and openfl 9.0.2

Comment: What about version of haxe?
https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel/issues/2294
Try OpenFL 8.9.0 and Lime 7.3.0 or haxe 4.1.x